# Sparse Matrix One 1 for Every Row

Tags: numpy

I would like to generate a random matrix `MxN` where every rows has just a single one in a random position. 
For example, I would a matrix like this:

```
Out[3]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

I tried with

```
M = 5
N = 3
arr = np.array([1]   + [0] * (N-1)) 
arr = np.tile(arr,(M,1))
np.random.shuffle(arr)
```

But it gives:

```
Out[75]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way to do this, but works:

```
def randOne():
    M = 5
    N = 3
    arr = np.zeros((M, N))
    for row in range(M):
        arr[row, np.random.randint(N)] = 1
    return arr


>>> randOne() array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

OR
Yup, there is a more elegant way to do this ;)

```
def randOne2(M=5, N=3): 
    arr = np.zeros((M, N), dtype=np.int8)
    arr[np.arange(M),np.random.randint(0,N,M)] = 1
    return arr


>>> randOne2()
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

Comment: what fs I had to generate random bistream like 1111000, 111110, 110000, i.e. the number of consecutive ones is random

Comment: Depending on how long you need you do something like `ones = np.random.randint(7) ‘1’*ones + ‘0’*(7-ones)`